# Is this the correct way to replace a string with the mean of a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have this data frame where in some columns of the data frame there is the word "None" as a string. I am trying to replace that string with the mean of the column instead. Is this the right way to do it, as it is not working:

```
X["column"] = X["column"].replace(to_replace="None", value = X["column"].mean())
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Is it the word "None" or is it python `None`?

Comment: I imagine "None" ( *the word "None" as a string* ), I think (python) None would behave like NaN.

Comment: Right so I guess the question is which part is the problem. If it was python None, then the mean would be correct but nothing would be replaced. If it is the word "None" then the mean couldn't be calculated. "it is not working" doesn't give information either way.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to replace "None" by NaN to be able to compute the mean. Then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with the value:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].replace("None", float('nan'))
df['column'] = df['column'].fillna(df['column'].mean())
```

Comment: Hi! Many thanks. This is my code right now, the first line you suggested works but the fillna() doesn't for some reason. Here is my code: `X["cough"] = X["cough"].replace("None", float('nan'))
X["cough"] = X["cough"].fillna(X["cough"].mean())`. The first replace works but then fillna() doesn't unfortunately.